# Can you get the same gwent card twice from one NPC?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Will I get multiple copies of a gwent card after a match with the same person?

I think I got it before with multiple matches with some merchant but I am not getting cards after a match. Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you only get the card from a merchant the first time you beat them. This is explained in a loading screen as mentioned in [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/702760-the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/71838221):

> I don't get anything after the first win, plus one of the loading screen tips said each gwent player has a card that you'll recieve the first time you beat them.
>
> Loading screen says you can only get one card.

The loading screen text is mentioned in [this list](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Loading_screen_hints_and_tips):

> 38. The total number of gwent cards you can win from merchants is limited, and you can only win one card from each merchant.

I can confirm by my personal experience that this is the case as well. I played the same NPC ~10 times to make money (pro tip: this is not a good money-making strategy) and I only got the card the first time I won against that person.